# Detect (catastrophic) cancellation in sums

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, floating-point

In finite precision arithmetic, what are ways to detect (catastrophic) cancellation when adding $N\in\mathbb{N}$ numbers?

Example ($N=2$): When adding two numbers $a$ and $b$ the result $a+b$ might be inaccurate due to cancellation if $a\approx -b$, which can be verified by checking if $|1+\frac{a}{b}| < \varepsilon$ for a sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$.

Is it similarly possible to check if the result of adding $N\ge 3$ numbers in any given order is likely to be inaccurate?

Comment: Which order are you adding those numbers?

Comment: My question is about any prescribed order, but an answer regarding a particular order such as descending or ascending would certainly also be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a rough estimate, compare the sum $S = \sum a_i$ with sum of the absolute values $A = \sum |a_i|$ or the maximum $M=\mathrm{max}\; |a_i|,$ i.e. look at the quotients $A/|S|$ or $M/|S|.$  You can get a more accurarate sum and better estimates, if you use compensated summation algorithms like [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).